# Is it possible to reuse cameras found in old flip phones?

Tags: camera, mobile-phone

Here's my phone: Samsung SPH-A620 / VGA1000 http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SPH-A620ZSSXAR-search/8

Is there a way to use just the camera component of this phone without the phone?

Comment: Unfortunately if you have to ask, then you nay not have the skill set to do it.  BTW there was a PBS Nova show about spy drones, and one had a wide-angle  high-resolution camera composed of over 300 phone-camera image sensors.

Comment: I checked out the drone you mentioned and it's super cool! Thanks for sharing. I had several phones like the one I mentioned and was thinking about putting the cameras together into a single unit. Eh...I can dream, can't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible, of course! Would it be easy? Hell no!

A novice could possibly pull this off if they had the data sheet for the camera itself. A pin out, plus operating characteristics would help you to model a circuit to drive the camera. However, turning the camera on is only step one. You need to figure out what type of signaling it uses for operation(shutter, zoom, etc) and how it saves the images you capture. Reverse-engineering those things in a piece of hardware would be a difficult task for even a seasoned electrical engineer. That is all assuming the camera can even be used outside of the phone's instructional environment.

So assume you had all the data necessary to do it, it probably still isn't worth it. There are [tons](https://www.google.com/search?q=raw%20digital%20camera&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl#rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&tbm=shop&q=micro%20camera) of micro cameras available for sale relatively cheap that can easily interface with current devices. Plus the resolution is no doubt much better than the one contained within that phone.

So to sum it all up you could certainly do it, but purchasing a newer camera will get you farther, faster, and possibly cheaper if you factor in your time as a cost.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight! I'm going to go throw away this phone. :)